# Changing function's default parameters in Python

Tags: python

Let's say this is the signature of my function:

```
def foo(x,y,z=0):
.
.
```

When I want to use this function, how can I override the value of z without changing the function or the signature?

Comment: What do you mean override?

Comment: Why would you change z's default value? The reason you change it in the first place is to be default.

Comment: Do you mean how to pass in a value for `z` when calling the function?

Comment: `def bar(x,y,z=5): return foo(x,y,z)`?

Comment: You can't. You could assign a *new* function object to the name `foo` with a different default that calls the old function object. Would that do?

Comment: Can't you simply pass the values to the function `foo(2,3,4)` ? Not used to python. Try this out though. In this case, `z would be assigned 4` .

Comment: Someone else wrote this function, and he defined it, now I have to use this function but with another value of z.

Comment: @ Moon Cheesez, yes.

Comment: You could keep calling the function as the need arises while passing different values as arguments. First call- `foo(2,3,4)` and second time may be `foo(2,3,8)`.....and so on. You can call a function more than once and pass different values for the parameters every time. There's no restriction for the values of arguments you pass neither for the number of calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just pass value explicitly.

```
def foo(x, y, z=0):
    print z

foo(1,3)
>> 0 # default value

foo(1,2,5)
>> 5 # new value passed
```